# Unable to connect to nginx from the very machine itself

Tags: nginx, local-area-network

I have no problem to connect to my nginx web server contents from remote machines using url like `http://foo.bar/media/baz.jpg` but when I try it inside the machine itself (or other machines in same network), the connection times out. If I replace `foo.bar` with `localhost` or local IP address, it returns 404.

My vHost file is like below:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name foo.bar;

        client_max_body_size 100M;
        proxy_read_timeout 1000s;

        access_log off;

        location /media/ {
                alias /home/foo/media/;
        }

        location /static/ {
                alias /home/foo/static_root/;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
        }
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/blahblah/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/blahblah/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

**PS**: If I add below record to `/etc/hosts` I can get it to work:

```
foo.bar 192.168.x.x #local IP address
```

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. To be able to help, can you please add your vHost in your question?

Comment: @LeRouteur thanks. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

If it is returning a 404 you are in fact connected to the server. But it seems if your virtual host is not configured to answer to this hostname/ip.

If there should only be one `server {}` block you could use the special value `_` (underscore) to let it answer for every name available or add `localhost` to your `server_name`s.

Comment: If I use local IP address, it return 404. But if I use original address, it just times out.